# Flexdashboard Sidebar Icon

Tags: r, shinydashboard, flexdashboard

I would like to ask how can I add icons to flexdashboard to look like in shinydashboard in sidebar section. Is it possible ?

R code below:

## Sidebar {.sidebar}

Website Content  **#here I would like to see icon**

ABST and Workflow Process  **#here I would like to see icon**

Global Repoting Team Process  **#here I would like to see icon**

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution by adding icon by css file. Below code does not work. Please advise.

```
p:after{
content: '';
display: block;
height: 20px;
width: 20px;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: -40px;
background: url("https://media.giphy.com/media/pAhJa87TXxJMA/giphy.gif")
```

}